# how to get the data in this Api using retrofit in android

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

I got a null pointer exception while fetching these details

```
                 "order": 8,
                "month": "November",
                "amount": "450",
                "given": "450",
                "date": "12-Sep-2018".
```

Can someone tell me how to get the data in this type of `JSON` format using `retrofit`?

```
 {
        "status": 1,
        "msg": "Data found Successfully..!",
        "data": [
            {
                "subject": "Tution Fee",
                "sequence": 1,
                "months": {
                    "7": {
                        "order": 7,
                        "month": "October",
                        "amount": "450",
                        "given": "450",
                        "date": "12-Sep-2018",
                        "status": "Paid"
                    },
                    "8": {
                        "order": 8,
                        "month": "November",
                        "amount": "450",
                        "given": "450",
                        "date": "12-Sep-2018",
                        "status": "Paid"
                    },
                    "9": {
                        "order": 9,
                        "month": "December",
                        "amount": "200",
                        "given": null,
                        "status": "Due"
                    },
                    "10": {
                        "order": 10,
                        "month": "January",
                        "amount": "450",
                        "given": null,
                        "status": "Due"
                    },
                    "11": {
                        "order": 11,
                        "month": "February",
                        "amount": "450",
                        "given": null,
                        "status": "Due"
                    },
                    "12": {
                        "order": 12,
                        "month": "March",
                        "amount": "450",
                        "given": null,
                        "status": "Due"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "subject": "Transport Fee",
                "sequence": 2,
                "months": {
                    "7": {
                        "order": 7,
                        "month": "October",
                        "amount": "400.00",
                        "given": "400",
                        "date": "12-Sep-2018",
                        "status": "Paid"
                    },
                    "8": {
                        "order": 8,
                        "month": "November",
                        "amount": "400",
                        "given": "400",
                        "date": "12-Sep-2018",
                        "status": "Paid"
                    },
                    "9": {
                        "order": 9,
                        "month": "December",
                        "amount": "400",
                        "given": null,
                        "status": "Due"
                    },
                    "10": {
                        "order": 10,
                        "month": "January",
                        "amount": "400.00",
                        "given": null,
                        "status": "Due"
                    },
                    "11": {
                        "order": 11,
                        "month": "February",
                        "amount": "400.00",
                        "given": null,
                        "status": "Due"
                    },
                    "12": {
                        "order": 12,
                        "month": "March",
                        "amount": "400.00",
                        "given": null,
                        "status": "Due"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "subject": "Other Fee",
                "sequence": 3,
                "months": {
                    "1": {
                        "order": 1,
                        "month": "Back_dues",
                        "amount": 300,
                        "given": 0,
                        "status": "Due"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "subject": "computer_test22",
                "sequence": 4,
                "months": {
                    "1": {
                        "order": 1,
                        "month": "April",
                        "amount": "100",
                        "given": "0",
                        "status": "Due"
                    },
                    "2": {
                        "order": 2,
                        "month": "May",
                        "amount": "100",
                        "given": "0",
                        "status": "Due"
                    },
                    "3": {
                        "order": 3,
                        "month": "June",
                        "amount": "100",
                        "given": "0",
                        "status": "Due"
                    },
                    "4": {
                        "order": 4,
                        "month": "July ",
                        "amount": "100",
                        "given": "0",
                        "status": "Due"
                    },
                    "5": {
                        "order": 5,
                        "month": "August",
                        "amount": "100",
                        "given": "0",
                        "status": "Due"
                    },
                    "6": {
                        "order": 6,
                        "month": "September",
                        "amount": "100",
                        "given": "0",
                        "status": "Due"
                    },
                    "7": {
                        "order": 7,
                        "month": "October",
                        "amount": "100",
                        "given": "0",
                        "status": "Due"
                    },
                    "8": {
                        "order": 8,
                        "month": "November",
                        "amount": "100",
                        "given": "0",
                        "status": "Due"
                    },
                    "9": {
                        "order": 9,
                        "month": "December",
                        "amount": "100",
                        "given": "0",
                        "status": "Due"
                    },
                    "10": {
                        "order": 10,
                        "month": "January",
                        "amount": "100",
                        "given": "0",
                        "status": "Due"
                    },
                    "11": {
                        "order": 11,
                        "month": "February",
                        "amount": "100",
                        "given": "0",
                        "status": "Due"
                    },
                    "12": {
                        "order": 12,
                        "month": "March",
                        "amount": "100",
                        "given": "0",
                        "status": "Due"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "current_status": {
            "subject": "Current Month-(July)",
            "amount": 8750,
            "given": 1700,
            "remain": 7050,
            "status": "due"
        }
    }
```

Comment: which language you're using please post some information what have tried so far.

Comment: Did you even go through documentation here  https://square.github.io/retrofit/ ? It's  self explanatory

Comment: type of your model class for "date" member?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this from you model object that you are using for retrofit response model. like hashMap<String,jsonObject>(), or you can use class object for "jsonObject" replacement

Answer (score 0):

Use Gson mapping, That will be the easy way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, create relevant models using serializing according to the response type.
Ex:

```
@SerializedName("status")
    private String status;
@SerializedName("msg")
    private String msg;
```

After, create default constructor and second constructor with the above strings. After that, you can create getters and setters according to used values.

```
public "ClassName"(
                String status,
                String msg) {
            this.status = status;
            this.msg = msg;
}


public String getstatus() {
        return status;
    }

public String getmsg() {
        return msg;
    }

public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

public void setMsg(String msg) {
        this.msg = msg;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, I used Gson mapping and done.

Ex : "subject": "Transport Fee",
"sequence": 2,
"months": {
"7": {

@SerializedName("subject")
private ArrayList subectList;

Inside of subject model:

@SerializedName("Transport")
private String Transport;

@SerializedName("sequence")
private int sequence;

@SerializedName("months")
private ArrayList months;